# Strong induction and mistake

Tags: induction

**what is the fault in this reasoning by  [strong induction](https://courses.cs.cornell.edu/cs2800/wiki/index.php/Strong_induction)**

For all  $ A $ and $ B $ of $ M_p (K) $ and
all integer $n$ we have: $ A ^ n B = B $

**The proof :**

Denote  $\forall n\in \mathbb N,\quad P (n) $ :  $ A ^ n B = B $

- The property is true at rank $ n = 0 $ because $ A ^ 0
   B = I_n B = B $
- Let $ n $ be a natural integer, suppose $ P (n) $
  true up to rank $ n $.
  $ A ^ {n + 1} B = A A ^ n B = AB $ (hypothesis at rank
  $ n $) and $ A B = B $ (assumption at rank $ 1 $)
  we thus obtain $ A ^ {n + 1} B = B $

and $ P (n + 1) $ is true

Comment: assumption at rank 1 is correct?

Comment: You start out OK at $n=0$ but you never get to $n=1,$ because the "proof" for $n=1$ requires that you already know $n=1$ is true.

Comment: we know that this is false, but the strong induction requires to verify only the hypothesis at n = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the inductive step you're only allowed to use previous steps. $P(1)$ is not a previous step for $P(1).$

The inductive step requires that $P(1)$ is already true, which is valid for $P(n)$ for all $n \geq2,$
but since you only have $P(0)$ as a base case you needed an inductive step that is valid for all $n \geq 1.$

Comment: The link I gave therefore contains an error ?

Comment: The link has one particularly bad defect, in my opinion, because it does not say what values of $n$ they mean. It should say something like "arbitrary $n$ where $n > 0.$" Moreover, even that wording requires a certain understanding of what they mean by "arbitrary" $n.$ What it ought to mean is, you have to prove an inductive step that is true no matter which $n$ it is applied to as long as $n$ is an integer and $n>0.$ It does not mean you get to pick your own choice of $n$ that can be as large as you want and only do a proof for that value of $n.$

Comment: The previous page, for weak induction, is a bit better, because in that case you're asked to prove $P(n+1)$ for arbitrary $n$, and in this case the arbitrary $n$ is any $n\in \mathbb N$, not just $n>0.$

Comment: They actually do say what they mean by "arbitrary": if you click on the word "arbitrary" it takes you here: https://courses.cs.cornell.edu/cs2800/wiki/index.php/Choose_an_arbitrary_value

Comment: Why negative votes, we are not allowed to ask a question even stupid?

Comment: You're right, I don't agree with the negative vote on the question. Your argument is actually a classic fallacy used in multiple "fake proofs" that people have made up to puzzle others, which makes it all the more legitimate as a question.

Comment: Thank's David 
for your explanation and support